# How to install Nvidia graphics driver version 415 on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: drivers

Title says it all. I want to drive my Nvidia Quadro P4200 with v415. Lots of sites give advice, but:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
 Fresh drivers from upstream, currently shipping Nvidia.

## Current Status

Current long-lived branch release: `nvidia-410` (410.66)
Dropped support for Fermi series (https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4656)

Old long-lived branch release: `nvidia-390` (390.87)

For GF1xx GPUs use `nvidia-390` (390.87)
For G8x, G9x and GT2xx GPUs use `nvidia-340` (340.107)
For NV4x and G7x GPUs use `nvidia-304` (304.137) End-Of-Life!

Support timeframes for Unix legacy GPU releases:
https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3142

## What we're working on right now:

- Normal driver updates
- Help Wanted: Mesa Updates for Intel/AMD users, ping us if you want to help do this work, we're shorthanded.

## WARNINGS:

This PPA is currently in testing, you should be experienced with packaging before you dive in here:

Volunteers welcome!

### How you can help:

## Install PTS and benchmark your gear:

    sudo apt-get install phoronix-test-suite

Run the benchmark:

    phoronix-test-suite default-benchmark openarena xonotic tesseract gputest unigine-valley

and then say yes when it asks you to submit your results to openbechmarking.org. Then grab a cup of coffee, it takes a bit for the benchmarks to run. Depending on the version of Ubuntu you're using it might preferable for you to grabs PTS from upstream directly: http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=downloads

## Share your results with the community:

Post a link to your results (or any other feedback to): https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers-testers

Remember to rerun and resubmit the benchmarks after driver upgrades, this will allow us to gather a bunch of data on performance that we can share with everybody.

If you run into old documentation referring to other PPAs, you can help us by consolidating references to this PPA.

If someone wants to go ahead and start prototyping on `software-properties-gtk` on what the GUI should look like, please start hacking!

## Help us Help You!

We use the donation funds to get the developers hardware to test and upload these drivers, please consider donating to the "community" slider on the donation page if you're loving this PPA:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:2 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic InRelease
Hit:3 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu cosmic-cran35/ InRelease                                                                                                                      
Hit:4 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                                             
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]                                         
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dyatlov-igor/sierra-theme/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease [83.2 kB]                                                         
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/font-manager/staging/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                       
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                                                     
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/forkotov02/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                             
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu cosmic InRelease         
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/docky/ubuntu cosmic InRelease           
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/scribus/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease            
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease         
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu cosmic InRelease       
Fetched 241 kB in 4s (60.7 kB/s)                   
Reading package lists... Done
```

Followed thereafter by:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic InRelease
Hit:2 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu cosmic-cran35/ InRelease                                                                                                                             
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dyatlov-igor/sierra-theme/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                                                        
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                                                                              
Hit:5 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                       
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease [83.2 kB]                                                                    
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]                                                          
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/font-manager/staging/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                      
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                                        
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/forkotov02/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease  
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu cosmic InRelease          
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/docky/ubuntu cosmic InRelease           
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/scribus/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease            
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease         
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu cosmic InRelease       
Fetched 241 kB in 4s (59.9 kB/s)                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

sudo apt install nvidia-415                    # There is no such package
sudo apt install nvidia-drivers-415            # There is no such package
sudo apt install nvidia-graphics-drivers-415   # There is no such package
```

These drivers are referenced in articles and press releases but no love. For example:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-graphics-drivers-415
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-415
```

And...

```
$ sudo apt-cache search 415
libgempc410 - PC/SC driver for the GemPC 410, 412, 413 and 415 smart card readers
libghc-haxr-dev - XML-RPC client and server library for Haskell
libghc-haxr-prof - XML-RPC client and server library for Haskell; profiling library
node-webfinger - Client library for Host Meta (RFC 6415) and Webfinger
swaml - Semantic Web Archive of Mailing Lists
libnvidia-compute-415 - NVIDIA libcompute package
```

I do not see the driver package listed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88317/discussion-on-question-by-lexible-how-to-install-nvidia-graphics-driver-version).

Answer (score 2):

You messed up the repository name a little bit.  The correct set of commands should be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-415
```

Please note that there is some naming error in the PPA:  The wesite lists the package as "nvidia-graphics-drivers-415" however the package in the PPA is "nvidia-driver-415"

Comment: Ah, I see I did. Unfortunately, I am getting exactly the same error after `apt update`. :(

Comment: @Lexible Did you re-run `sudo apt update`?  Whici version of Ubuntu are you running.

Comment: Yes. And 18.10 (with the 4.20 kernel)

Comment: @Lexible OK - I mounted the PPA in one of my CPUs.  There is a spelling error in the title, and all of the works in the package title do not have 's', and omit to work 'graphic'.  Please try `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-415`

Comment: Please also note that there are many warnings that this is an experimental PPA....